# Show any number of text and checkbox in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkbox and a label side by side in an html

```
<div class ="followupSteps">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFollowup">
  <label for="checkboxFollowup" id="labelFollowup"></label>
</div>
```

Depending on the number of output returned from server side, there can be any number of checkbox and label. For example, if 5 outputs are returned from the server, there will be 5 rows (each row is 1 checkbox and 1 label). How do I do that?

In jQuery, I have `$("#labelFollowup").text(somevar);`but it will not create a new row. Rather it will keep replacing the content of the only one label defined in the html.

Comment: You need to show us the code that generates the repeated inputs and labels.

Comment: You just need to loop through the returned data then `clone()` and `append()` the new rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  let div = '<div class ="followupSteps">'+
  '<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFollowup">'+
  '<label for="checkboxFollowup" id="labelFollowup">label</label>'+
  '</div>';
  for(var index=0; index<5; index++)
    {
      $('table').append('<tr> <td>'+div+' </td> </tr>')
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
```

try this one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $followupDiv = $('.followupSteps');
var $inputClone = $('input', $followupDiv).clone().removeAttr('id');
var $labelClone = $('label', $followupDiv).clone().removeAttr('id');

var serverResponse = 5;

for (i = 1; i <= serverResponse; i++) {
  $inputClone.clone().attr('id', 'checkboxFollowup' + i).appendTo($followupDiv);
  $labelClone.clone().attr('id', 'labelFollowup' + i).appendTo($followupDiv);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="followupSteps">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFollowup">
  <label for="checkboxFollowup" id="labelFollowup"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you doesn't provide much information, I will just post how you can achieve it using a javascript "for" loop of 10 times and following your markup:

```
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
       $('#checkboxFollowup').eq(0).clone().prop('id', 'clone'+i).appendTo('.followupSteps');
       $('#labelFollowup').eq(0).clone().prop('id', 'clone'+i).appendTo('.followupSteps');
    }
```

Using the following jQuery methods:

1. https://api.jquery.com/eq/
2. https://api.jquery.com/clone/
3. http://api.jquery.com/appendto/
4. http://api.jquery.com/prop/